# load a local pdf with url in xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, file, url, local, xcode4.6

i just bought Sam's teach yourself ios6 in 24 hours and was reading through a chapter where he loads a url  thru an NSMutableArray like so (populates a UITableView as well):

```
[systemTopics addObject:@{@"name":@"General",
                        @"picture":@"Hyacinth.png",
                        @"url":@"http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_(flower)"}];
```

how could I modify this to load a local pdf file instead of the wiki pages?
I tried file:/// thinking it would work, but no luck.
I know there's many ways to skin a cat, but his example meets 99% of my requirements and I only need this one mod to start building content for my app.
Thank you in advance.
P

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, local resources are accessed through [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBundle) objects. If the PDFs are in your Xcode project's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, then you'll be able to access them through your main bundle. You can ask the bundle for a URL for a given resource like this (assume it's called "Awesome.pdf":

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Awesome" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

So, to apply it directly to your snippet:

```
NSString* pdfURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Awesome" withExtension:@"pdf"] absoluteString];
[systemTopics addObject:@{@"name":@"General",
                        @"picture":@"Hyacinth.png",
                        @"url":pdfURL}];
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Currently there are 23 instances of the above code with the url that I need to swap for local pdf files. how would i implement your bit of code that many times?

Comment: There are any number of ways to do that. A little utility function that takes a PDF name and returns a URL sounds like a fine idea.

Comment: do you do contract work? i just need a skeleton app that i can fill with content.

Comment: I'm not in the contract work business. This is a pretty simple change though. Take the opportunity to tinker and learn a bit.